# Openlayers 2.13 not calling correct XYZ tiles from couchdb?

Tags: openlayers-2, couchdb

End goal is to be able to access a pouchdb of map tiles on phone off-line that has been synced from remote couchdb of map tiles.

Openlayers is not calling the correct document from the couchdb to test before using pouchdb.  The Z parameter is correct, but the X & Y parameters are not close to what they should be when examining the database or original mbtiles data.

Example:

- In plain files converted with mb-util from mbtiles database for Revelstoke trails, tiles are: z=11,x=351,y=684,685
- In contrast Openlayers calls: z=11,x=53-59,y=89-92 for about the same region

Done so far

- Built a couchdb of map tiles from a mbtiles database with Mapproxy
- Built with both SW origin & NW origin
- Projections: 900913/3857
- Tiles display directly in futon as tile attachment
- Pouchdb syncs to couchdb
- Openlayers requests tiles outside the current tiles set

My non-working Openlayers code using XYZ:

```
var bc_orm_trails_couchdbLayerXYZ = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("BC ORM trails couchdb local",
    ["http://localhost:5984/tiles_sw/SWoriginMercator-${z}-${x}-${y}/tile"], {
    spericalMercator: true,
    displayProjection: geographic,
    maxScale: "1000",
    minScale: "220000",
    maxExtent: BC,
    isBaseLayer: false,
    displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
    visibility: true
});

trails_mobileMap.addLayer(bc_orm_trails_couchdbLayerXYZ);
```

Tried pulling from local plain file folders created with mb-util to simplify -> doesn't work

```
var bc_orm_trails_plaintilesLayerXYZ = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("BC ORM trails plain tiles local",
        ["./data/tiles/trails/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"], {
    spericalMercator: true,
    displayProjection: geographic,
    maxScale: "1000",
    minScale: "220000",
    maxExtent: BC,
    isBaseLayer: false,
    displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
    visibility: true
});

trails_mobileMap.addLayer(bc_orm_trails_plaintilesLayerXYZ);
```

This works from a remote php TileServer with same mbtiles data:

```
var bc_orm_trails_mbtilesLayerTileServer = new OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ("BC ORM trails",
        ["http://tiles-alpha.xxxxxxxxxx.xx/trails.mbtiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"], {
    type: "png",
    projection: spherical_mercator,
    displayProjection: geographic,
    //maxScale: "52000",
    //minScale: "220000",
    isBaseLayer: false,
    displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
    visibility: false
});

trails_mobileMap.addLayer(bc_orm_trails_mbtilesLayerTileServer);
```

I think I either have a problem with origin (SW vs NW) or possible a projection issue but have run out of possible solutions.

Ideas or possible solutions?

Comment: Because X is so far off, I would surmise I have a projection issue.  Question is why do the present projections work for the remote tile server, but not locally?

Comment: Tested in Leaflet.  It just works!

Was looking at a future rewite of 2 yrs of Openlayers code to ol-3 for the Fall.  Looks like I will be rewriting everything in Leaflet for now.

Comment: Also works well in ol3.  Currently rewriting my app code in ol3.